# vba use strings with data and typetexts

Tags: string, vba, copy-paste

```
Dim price As String
price = Sheet1.Cells(39, 2).Copy: wdapp.Selection.PasteAndFormat xlValue
.TypeText "The following agreement price is" & price & "wsfwfwf"
```

This is the result i'm gettting...Why True? and the number before? can someone please explain thanks!

$25,819.80

The following agreement price isTrue$25,819.80

an annual payment of.

Comment: try just the `price = Sheet1.Cells(39, 2)` part without the copy and paste.

Comment: I need the formating though for the comma places

Comment: Then `price = Format(Sheet1.Cells(39, 2),"$#,##0.00")`

Comment: Try `price = Sheet1.Cells(39, 2).text`